# Angular CLI proxy to .NET Core on https doesnt work

Tags: .net, proxy, .net-core, angular-cli

I have a .NET Core api running on localhost:5000 thats configured to serve the static output from `ng build`. When in development I'd like to run my angular cli server with `ng serve` vs `ng build --watch` (mostly for convenience reasons).

I tried to run it with all the different proxy settings and suggestions out there but I think the issue is that my API is running on https and every suggestion defaults to `secure: false`. Is there something else I need to do to configure the proxy for https?

My proxy.conf.json should work pretty simply as the following since I dont need to change the origin or rewrite anything:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:5000",
    "secure": true
  }
}
```

The error I get in the console is:

> [HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request https://localhost:5000/api/values from localhost:4200 to https://localhost:5000 (EPROTO)

Answer (score 0):

since your API is running on https you should access it with http**S**:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "https://localhost:5000",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

The `"secure": false` means that you accept that backend server is running on HTTPS with an invalid certificate; I suspect you do use an invalid (hand-made) certificate; *reference*: search `secure: false` [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/) then see the explanation above.